# overriding url rewriting for $_GET variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have a page in my admin system with the following path:

> http://192.168.1.253/xxxxxx/admin/view/news-items/issue/3

I am trying to rewrite it so that it directs to:

> http://192.168.1.253/xxxxxx/admin/view/news-items.php?issue=3

However I cannot seem to make it work, as the page displays but the php cannot detect a $_GET variable. I have 2 .htaccess files, one in the xxxxxx directory and one in the admin directory. here they are:

xxxxxx:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/delete/(1-9)/?$ $1.php?delete=$2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L] # rewrite without query string parameters
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php\#$2 [L] # one name string parameter
```

admin:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L] # rewrite without query string parameters
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L] # one id parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/issue/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?issue=$2 [L] # one issue parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&file_id=$3 [L] # two parameters
```

**Edit**

Here is the new code :

xxxxxx:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

#RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/delete/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?delete=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA] # rewrite without query string parameters
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php\#$2 [L,QSA] # one name string parameter
```

admin:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

#RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA] # rewrite without query string parameters
#RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA] # one id parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/issue/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?issue=$2 [L,QSA] # one issue parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&file_id=$3 [L,QSA] # two parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `[QSA]` flag in your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/delete/(1-9)/?$ $1.php?delete=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA] # rewrite without query string parameters
# etc.
```

From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the `[QSA]` flag.

Comment: It is still doing the same thing as before after I added the QSA to each rule :/. Please see above.

Comment: @Phil Please add `,R=302` into flags -- this will do temp redirect -- so that you will see rewritten URLs in your browser address bar. If it's rewritten correctly but you still cannot obtain those variables, then it's either some another rule elsewhere ... or some code in your PHP script (could be other reasons, bit those 2 are more likely).